# When i call a method to return a value, it resets it back to 0

Tags: java, swing

```
public void setSavingsBal(String q) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    try
        {
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logininf.txt"));
           String l = "";

           while ((l = in.readLine())!=null)
           {
             String [] var = l.split("#");
             if(var[0].equals(q))
             {  
                 System.out.println(var[2]);
                 savingsBal = Double.parseDouble(var[2]);

             }
           }

        }
```

above it savingsBal has the value of 20

```
public double getSavingsBal()
{
        System.out.println(savingsBal);
    return savingsBal;
}
```

but when I retrieve it, it gives the value of 0

```
private void btnGetBalanceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Client cl1 = new Client();
    double balance;
    balance = cl1.getSavingsBal();
```

it seems as if the variable has not updated after the original set method.

Comment: It looks like in the method where you retrieve, you create a new 'Client' object, and then call get on that. When was the set method called? Unless that variable is static, the variable will be 0 for that instance.

Comment: It was called in a previous form, before the set method. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself correctly I'm pretty new to coding

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a completely new Client object within your btnGetBalanceActionPerformed method, and this object has no connection with any existing Client. So even though you change the balance somewhere in an existing Client object, this state change will not be seen in the new one, cl1, that you've created here. Solution: don't create a new Client object, but rather use the existing one. How will depend on code not shown since you'll need to somehow get and use a reference to the existing one.

So instead of:

```
private void btnGetBalanceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Client cl1 = new Client();
    double balance;
    balance = cl1.getSavingsBal();
```

do:

```
private void btnGetBalanceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // Client cl1 = new Client();
    double balance;
    balance = existingClientReference.getSavingsBal();
```

Note that you will want to avoid trying to solve this with static variables.

Comment: Its not working, maybe because I am calling the value when I am in a different for than when I used the set method?

Comment: @ShailenDesai: I'm not trying to be blunt, but there's no way on earth anyone can guess why it's not working based on what you've posted so far. Hopefully you're not blindly copying my code above and expecting it to work since it was not meant to, but rather to convey the idea that you have to use your own Client variable (a non-static class field), whatever you've named it.

Comment: @ShailenDesai: to get a more complete answer, you will need to show more pertinent code, preferably a [mcve]. Also, when posting code, please take care to format it well so that we can more easily read and understand it.